# Error parsing 16 bit short

Tags: java, parsing, primitive, short

> short: The short data type is a 16-bit signed two's complement integer. It has a minimum value of -32,768 and a maximum value of 32,767 (inclusive)

Why does the following

```
System.out.println(Short.parseShort("1111111111111111", 2));
```

Return

```
java.lang.NumberFormatException: Value out of range.
```

> An exception of type NumberFormatException is thrown if any of the following situations occurs:
>
> - The first argument is null or is a string of length zero.
> - The radix is either smaller than Character.MIN_RADIX or larger than Character.MAX_RADIX.
> - Any character of the string is not a digit of the specified radix, except that the first character may be a minus sign '-' ('\u002D') or plus sign '+' ('\u002B') provided that the string is longer than length 1.
> - The value represented by the string is not a value of type short.

I assume the error is from the last bullet, but
I thought 16 '1' bits is equivalent to -1 when using Short. Thus, it should be valid?

Comment: Because `short` is **signed**.  That binary value represents the maximum value of an **unsigned** `short`.

Comment: Because binary number `1111111111111111` is the decimal number `65,535`, and you just said yourself that *"maximum value of `32,767`"*, so why is that confusing you?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The javadoc that you quoted states that `Short.parseShort` parses numbers as signed numbers.

`1111111111111111` (16 `1` digits) when read as a signed number means 2<sup>16</sup> - 1 or 65535.  That is too large to be represented as a `short`.

Alternatives:

- If there was an alternative to `parseShort` that parsed unsigned values, that would work.  (But there isn't ...)
- You could use `Integer.parseInt`, do a range check on the `int` result, and then cast it to a `short`.

---

> I thought 16 '1' bits is equivalent to -1 when using Short. Thus, it should be valid?

Unfortunately, no.  The `parseInt` method parses signed values.

Thought experiment: what if the user entered `1111111111111111` with the intention that it really meant a positive *signed* number; i.e. +65535?  How would that mesh with your idea that the parse method treats signed and unsigned as interchangeable?

Comment: Oh. It was that simple

Answer (score 3):

`1111111111111111` should be converted to `65535`, which is greater than the maximum value(32,767) `short` can represent. Try some smaller numbers.